# Web scrape for FIFA match statistics using R

Tags: r, rvest

For 2018 FIFA world cup, FIFA offer statistics for each match. say France ver Argentina at https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331537/#match-statistics

I currently using rvest for scrape.

```
v.url <- 'https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331537/#match-statistics'

df.extraction <- read_html(v.url) %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1] %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]]
```

While it return nothing.

Any one have experience to extract above statistics?

Comment: That site looks like it's live-updating with JavaScript, which rvest can't run. You could use a scraper that can run JavaScript, or maybe more simply scrape the underlying APIs, which you can see through your browser's page inspector pane, e.g. `response <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/live/football/17/254645/275093/300331537?language=en-GB')`

Comment: Sorry that I m new to web scraping. Do u have example sample code for similar web scrape exercise?

Comment: https://datascienceplus.com/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/

Comment: http://www.rladiesnyc.org/post/scraping-javascript-websites-in-r/

Comment: @alistaire there is error message with Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Failed to connect to api.fifa.com port 443: Connection refused. Any other package it is required ?

Comment: [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/) may be useful to diagnose the problem and send a more carefully-crafted GET request

Comment: thanks @alistaire i able to use jsonlite to retrieve the data now. Thanks for your gentle help.

Comment: Sorry that how u can find the link? https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/live/football/17/254645/275093/300331537?language=en-GB

Comment: Open the page in a browser and open the developer tools; one of the tabs is usually network requests.

Comment: Thanks again @alistaire. I would like to retrieve all match statistics while i unable to figure the logic of the link. 1st component https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/live/football/17/254645/ 2nd component 275073 (group stage) or 275093 (knockout stage) and 3rd component is match id (3003-31537). Do u think there is logic for the link?